# Flash video: only make video full screen, not entire stage

Tags: flash, actionscript, fullscreen

I have a FLV playing in Flash with a full screen button. The problem is I want only the video to be shown full screen, not the entire stage. This is the code I'm using to make the video fullscreen.

```
function fullScreenUP(event:MouseEvent):void { 

  if (screenCheck == false) {

        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
        screenCheck = true;

      } else {

         stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
         screenCheck = false;
      }
```

}

Comment: As far as I know, when you go full screen, everything has to go full screen. You could hide everything on the stage though except for the video when in full screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FLVPlayback component has a fullScreenTakeOver property for dealing with this kind of things:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#fullScreenTakeOver

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, when you go full screen, everything has to go full screen. You could hide everything on the stage though except for the video when in full screen.

Answer (score 1):

If your video is being played using a Video object. You can also check out the fullScreenRect property

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html

The way it works is that you specify a rectangle for the viewport you want when the display changes to fullscreen.

Hope this helps.